# Sum of column values in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use these following code to calculating summation of a specific row in the database and show it in a new row under that intention column. but i will encounter an error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Fee"].Value.ToString());
}

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataRow row = ds.Tables["Entry"].NewRow();
ds.Tables["Entry"].Rows.Add(row);
```

I want to know how can I see the sum in a new row.

Comment: You should consider using LINQ to SQL here rather than using data sets.  You can write more natural queries with compile-time support.

Comment: the question is how can i show sum in the new row?

Comment: @aliprogrammer you have a history of asking the same question multiple times - you are likely to discourage the community from ever helping you again.

Answer (score 3):

i think the error is in the loop statement:

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Fee"].Value.ToString());
}
```

use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Fee"].Value.ToString());
}
```

you are starting at `Index zero` so you should *deduct one* for the total number of rows. It will return `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when it reaches on:

```
sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[dt.Rows.Count].Cells["Fee"].Value.ToString());
```

**because such row does not exists.**

**UPDATE 1**

after the loop, insert this statement:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", "", sum)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Fee"].Value.ToString());
}

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);

DataRow row = ds.Tables["Entry"].NewRow();
row[0] = "";
row[1] = "";
row[2] = sum;
ds.Tables["Entry"].Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: it will compute the summation. the question is how show the sum in the new row under Fee column?

Comment: Where will you put the sum of the new row?

Comment: so you mean that the result will be shown on the same grid (dataGridView1)? Can you add the number of columns in your grid?

Comment: yes. i want to show the summation of fees in a new row under last row of datagridview1 under Fee column?

Comment: ok, i got your point. Is your datagridview binded to a dataset? because you cannot manually add new row if it is binded. How many columns do you have in the datagridview? or the number of columns in the dataset.

Comment: AlloUserToAddNewRow is true. so there's no problem to add a new row. i have 3 columns. (SprotID) (SportName) (Fee). i want to see the summation of fees in a new row under fee column

Comment: after the Loop, add this statement: `dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", "", sum)`

Comment: it said : rows cannot programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound

Comment: I already asked you about that. `Is your datagridview binded to a dataset?` well, if that's the case, you need to add a row manually in the dataset. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I assumed that your datagridview1 is binded at `ds.Tables["Entry"]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. but i got another problem for this line "DataRow row = ds.Tables["Entry"].NewRow();" it said " Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 2):

'ds' doesn't have a table 'Entry', that's why you get a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

Comment: +1: and I'd not recommend extracting data straight from the DGV. Use a datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is not very clear but Check out the loop either access value from datatable or from grid
Like

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (dt.Rows[i]["Fee"].Value !=null)
   sum += int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["Fee"].Value.ToString());
}
```

And also make sure dt.Rows[i]["Fee"] does not contain null values
Even you can use Compute method to do the sum.

Comment: Re Bind the DS to the grid after adding new row. What you are doing to add new row seems fine. I hope you are assigning values in Row and then adding it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use compute method in datatable. get result from compute method then create new row from datatable then assign to appropriate field. then add the new row to datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the debugger and see where exactly this error occurs :)

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen if the DB returns null for one "FEE" cell.
Run it and see where are you exactly and look at the values, if you see a null you'll need if != null.