# new summation row in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum of column values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473940/sum-of-column-values-in-c-sharp)

i use these following codes to see the result of the summation in the new row. i have three columns. (SportID) (SportName) (Fee). i want to show the summation of fees in a new row under the fee column. but it will encounter a problem. please help me to solve it.
Any help will be appreciated

```
    int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Fee"].Value.ToString());
}

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);

DataRow row = ds.Tables["Entry"].NewRow();
row[0] = "";
row[1] = "";
row[2] = sum;
ds.Tables["Entry"].Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @CraigSchwarze this line "DataRow row = ds.Tables["Entry"].NewRow();" it said " Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

I think this line should be:

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
-------
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
```

Or add this line:

```
ds.Tables[0].TableName="Entry";
```

Comment: when i use index 0 for the table it tell me this error " **input string was not in a correct format.Couldent's store <> in SportID column. Expected type is Int32.**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception on the following line:

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables["Entry"].NewRow();
```

Probably because your ds doesn't have any table or the name of the table is different. Put a break point and see the dataset in visual debugger or try to access the table with index

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); //assuming you have table on 0 index
```

You can also check for

```
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
```

Comment: when i use index 0 for the table it tell me this error " **input string was not in a correct format.Couldent's store <> in SportID column. Expected type is Int32.**

Comment: @aliprogrammer, what are you talking about ? are you passing "0" or just 0 ? it should be simple 0 not with quotes

Comment: @aliprogrammer, where are you getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I shows that table **Entry** exists in your dataset?

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables["Entry"].NewRow();
```

You can avoid the exception by checking if the table exists in the dataset or not

```
if(ds.Tables["Entry"] != null)
```

You should add the table named **Entry** before accessing it. If you don't know the name then you can access the table with its index.

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
```

Comment: I have Entry table name.

Comment: @aliprogrammer Please verify the spellings and C# is case sensitive off-course

Comment: when i use index 0 for the table it tell me this error " **input string was not in a correct format.Couldent's store <> in SportID column. Expected type is Int32.**

Comment: @aliprogrammer which column of the table is "SportID", seems it's either row[0] or row[1]. you have to set the int value for it